# Where is NSTextfield Validates Immediately?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nstextfield

I have set it before but I cannot find the option any more...

[alt text http://www.joelsaltzman.com/pics/ib.png](http://www.joelsaltzman.com/pics/ib.png)

Answer (score 5):

That is an option that is available when you use bindings to connect your text field.

Comment: AAHHHH!!!!

Thank you SOOOO MUCH. It was in the bindings like you said. I feel dumb.